# How to resize space from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, resizing

I am trying to insert the unallocated space to `/dev/sda11` but it cant be done

I previously freed some space from my Windows partition then swapped off linux-swap then added the space to it then resized it again 
so how to do that ?

I am running on dual boot Windows 8, Ubuntu 14.04

Please explain as I am new to Linux

[image]